# Intermittent UnknownHostException on connecting Atlas MongoDB

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect my Spring Boot Java Application (Running on EKS - AWS Kubernetes) on Atlas MongoDB Cluster.
Sometimes my application can connect on Atlas and sometimes i can't connect and give me stack trace bellow (intermittent issue).

```
INFO 1 --- [nio-8060-exec-8] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=primary-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: primary-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: primary-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net}}, ServerDescription{address=secondary-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: secondary-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: secondary-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net}}, ServerDescription{address=third-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: third-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: third-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
INFO 1 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server secondary-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: secondary-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net: Try again at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:188) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: secondary-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net: Try again
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:186) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dev.morphia.morphia</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Connection string (suggested by Atlas MongoDB)**:

```
    mongodb://<username>:<password>@secondary-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net:27017,third-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net:27017,primary-shard.yyyy.mongodb.net:27017/<database>?ssl=true&replicaSet=RSNAME-shard-X&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

**Note**: I'm try to apply changes bellow but didn't work

- insert (exclude = { MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class }) on @EnableAutoConfiguration
- insert -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
- change my mongo-db-driver to latest version
- check whitelist cluster mongodb but is ok

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you might be having network issues instead of a configuration issue.

Comment: That is a problem with your DNS service. Talk to you network administrator about that. It is not a programming problem.

Comment: I think that is no network issue because i try to use nslookup and others tools to test connection between my node and atlas mongodb server and has connection.